# Does LVM support unwritten extents?

Tags: lvm

I want to tune samba on a system that has LVM2 under it. I have started to read an [article](http://www.eggplant.pro/blog/faster-samba-smb-cifs-share-performance/) which made me to ask this question, if my partition supports unwritten extents or not, I couldn't find it by googling it.

Comment: What matters is the file system you put on top of that LV. LVM or partitions or full disks just give you a block device, _unwritten extents_ are irrelevant to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Stéphane Chazelas said, LVM is irrelevant.

You can see what type of partition table you use for example by `mount`.

I have ext4 on top of my LVM, but adding to my samba config the `strict allocate = Yes` did stop my samba working, being accessible.